# Super slow load data infile when deleting duplicate rows

Tags: mysql

I encounter an issue while I load data in my mysql database. I use this as a way to insert data in my database :

```
USE database;
ALTER TABLE country
ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_name (`insee_code`,`post_code`,`city`);

LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/wamp64/tmp/myfile-csv'
                         REPLACE
                         INTO TABLE `country` CHARACTER SET utf8
                         FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
                         LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
                         IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

While my table are simply:

```
CREATE TABLE `country` (`insee_code`  VARCHAR(250),
                        `post_code`   VARCHAR(250),
                        `city`        VARCHAR(250));
```

Before I use a php script to load other tables, it's pretty fast (3GB in 3 minutes) but with this one, it takes 17 min to 
load 1 GB.

I don't know why, because with index, some rows are lost or corrupted and I'm just wondering why. If someone has an other way to delete duplicates rows while loading data from a CSV, I'll appreciate to ear it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats the engine on that table ? MyISAM, InnoDB or other?

Comment: In your previous usage of loading data, did the table also have a unique constraint on it?  I might suggest removing that constraint, loading, and then just doing a single cleanup job on MySQL after all data has loaded.

Comment: The engine of this table is MyISAM 
The previous tables didn't have a constraint on it just a primary key.
I can't remove this constraint because if I do, mySQL return me error code 1062.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a `REPLACE` you basically delete the row first, then insert the new row. What you want to do is `IGNORE` instead.

- read more about it here: [13.2.7 LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html)

> The REPLACE and IGNORE keywords control handling of input rows that
>   duplicate existing rows on unique key values:
>
> - If you specify REPLACE, input rows replace existing rows. In other words, rows that have the same value for a primary key or unique index
>     as an existing row. See Section 13.2.9, “REPLACE Syntax”.
> - If you specify IGNORE, rows that duplicate an existing row on a unique key value are discarded. For more information, see Comparison
>     of the IGNORE Keyword and Strict SQL Mode.

Also it would be better, if you would add a primary key. If you don't , MySQL creates one implicitly for you. This one is not visible and is either a uuid or a bigint. I don't remember that clearly. Anyway this is not optimal performance- and storagewise. Execute this:

```
ALTER TABLE country ADD column id int unsigned auto_increment primary key;
```

Comment: It works fine for me thanks, I have an execution time of 9 min and 30 sec.
A primary key is always needed ?